# Can not login to website with Invoke-Webrequest

Tags: powershell, webautomation

would like to logon to XING (social network) to read my status updates. But I can't seem get it working. I dont get any specific error, but the login-request returns a site saying "login trouble, try again blabla".

```
$loginURL = "https://login.xing.com"
$username = "throughx@gmx.net" # test account
$password = "1qayxsw2"

$req = Invoke-WebRequest $loginURL -SessionVariable Xing

$form = $req.Forms[0]
$form.fields["login_form_username"] = $username
$form.fields["login_form_password"] = $password
$req2 = Invoke-WebRequest $form.Action -WebSession $Xing -Method POST -Body $form
```

I compared (with Fiddler) what is being sent by this code, with a successful login via browser and apart from the token, its the same. 
Thanks!

Update: For testing purposes, I added the credentials of a test-account.

Comment: yes it does. $form.action contains the complete URL "https://login.xing.com/login"

Comment: Is your password correct?  The 'y' character doesn't match your keyboard walking pattern.

Comment: yes, (its a german keyboard layout)

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 How would I verify the get/post part? As I said I used Fiddler to compare manual vs. PoSh login and it looked fine.

Comment: So in Fiddler you're POSTing?

Comment: So, I was able to verify it. Manual Login and login with Invoke-webrequest, both "POST" headers